# Javascript Split String into Array of Arrays and not object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a string as input :

```
'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL'
```

and i need to split the same into Array of Arrays , something like :

```
[[PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS],[PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL]]
```

I tired split on '-' , but that gives me an object with 2 keys , is there any other way to achieve this.

If required i can split

Solution Tired but did not worked:

```js
const params = {postAuthActionId: 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL'};
const result = params.postAuthActionId.split('-').map((s) => s.split(','));
console.log(result);
console.log(typeof result);
```

Comment: When I run your code I get exactly what you asked for.  Split never creates an object, always an array.

Comment: Arrays are objects. The keys are the indexes.

Comment: As @Barmar - arrays are objects. If you check `typeof` of `result` it will display object. Please try: `console.log(Array.isArray(result) ? 'yes, its an array' : 'no, its not an array');`

Answer (score 1):

`split` the string on `-` , and when you `map` over each element of the array return a new array, coercing the number from a string.

```js
const params = {
  postAuthActionId: 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL'
};

const arr = params.postAuthActionId.split('- ');

const result = arr.map(el => {
  const [ id, number, status ] = el.split(', ');
  return [id, Number(number), status]
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

Demo **:**

```js
const str = 'PARTIALREFUND, 50, SUCCESS - PARTIALREFUND, 50, FAIL';

const arr = str.split(' - ');

const res = arr.map(item => {
    return [...item.split(', ')]
});

console.log(res);
```